# How to disable all the buttons in ListView items when click on button that is inside ListView in android

Tags: android, listview, listitem

I have a list view and inside each list-item I have a `TextView` and a `Button` like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
              android:gravity="right">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button_listItem_action"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1.2"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView_listItem_provider_address"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:textDirection="rtl"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

What I'd want to do is that I want to set a click listener for each button in each list-item that disables all other buttons in other list-items in this list view. I don't know if I should put this listener in the adapter or not and I have no idea how to work this.

Here's my adapter:

```
public class ProviderListArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Provider> {

    private static class ViewHolder{
        TextView txtViewAddress;
        Button buttonAction;
    }

    public ProviderListArrayAdapter(Context context, List<Provider> providers) {
        super(context, -1, providers);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        final Provider provider = getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_provider_selector, parent, false);
            viewHolder.txtViewAddress = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_listItem_provider_address);
            viewHolder.buttonAction = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_listItem_action);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.txtViewAddress.setText(provider.address);
        viewHolder.buttonAction.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //don't know what to do
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

ps: provider class is has just a string text for address.

Any help would be seriously appreciated.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep track of what the last clicked button was.  So have a variable in your class

```
int mLastSelected = -1;  //This is the position last selected or -1 if none is selected
```

Then in your getView, call

```
holder.buttonAction.setEnabled(mLastSelected == -1 || mLastSelected == position);
```

That will disable it if any other button was selected.  Then your onClick becomes

```
mLastSelected = position;
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

That will write the last selected variable and force the entire list to redraw itself.  When that happens all the buttons but the one you just pressed will become disabled.